# Failed to set remote audio description send parameters for m-section

Tags: reactjs, go, webrtc

**EDIT: No error occurs in firefox. This only seems to occur in Chrome.**

I am trying to get a web client connected to a WebRTC SFU, and simply send some audio in Opus format.

Here is the client code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/webrtc-test-20w7v?file=/src/App.tsx

The server code takes in an SDP and creates an answer :

```golang
// SDPHandler handles webrtc peer connection attempts
func (api API) SDPHandler(c echo.Context) error {
    ctx := c.(hm.HarmonyContext)
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(ctx.Request().Body)
    if err != nil {
        return ctx.NoContent(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity)
    }

    m := webrtc.MediaEngine{}
    m.RegisterCodec(webrtc.NewRTPOpusCodec(webrtc.DefaultPayloadTypeOpus, 90000))

    mediaAPI := webrtc.NewAPI(webrtc.WithMediaEngine(m))

    offer := webrtc.SessionDescription{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &offer); err != nil {
        return ctx.NoContent(http.StatusBadRequest)
    }

    peerConnection, err := mediaAPI.NewPeerConnection(api.peerConnectionConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error making peer connection", err)
        return ctx.NoContent(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    if _, err := peerConnection.AddTransceiverFromKind(webrtc.RTPCodecTypeAudio); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error adding transceiver", err)
        return ctx.NoContent(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    peerConnection.OnTrack(api.OnTrackStart(peerConnection))

    if err := peerConnection.SetRemoteDescription(offer); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error setting remote description", err)
        return ctx.NoContent(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    answer, err := peerConnection.CreateAnswer(nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error making answer", err)
        return ctx.NoContent(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    if err := peerConnection.SetLocalDescription(answer); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error setting local description", err)
        return ctx.NoContent(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    return ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, answer)
}
```

When I try to create a session, I have receive the following error:

```
Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Failed to set remote audio description send parameters for m-section with mid='0'.
```

Any ideas on what the issue with my code is?

Comment: webrtc.DefaultPayloadTypeOpus, 90000
-- opus is defined with a sampling rate of 48000 (and stereo). Compare your rtpmap line to the one generated by chrome or firefox.

Comment: thank you so much for the tip. After I lowered the sampling rate to 48000, the error was fixed. Just out of curiosity, what should I do if I wanted to raise or lower the bitrate of an opus track?

Comment: use the RTCRtpSender.setParameters API. Like https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/ but for audio instead of video.